# Is it possible for a creature to have bulletproof skin?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

Is it biologically possible for a creature to have bulletproof skin?

Note: To qualify as a bulletproof, the skin must be at the very least able to withstand small arms fire.

Perhaps I didn't make myself clear I'm talking about skin so hard it's bulletproof. Not about bulletproof bones or having fat so thick bullets can't hurt your internal organs I'm talking about having bulletproof skin.

Comment: You might want to read the sections in the other answers to the other question talking about the difference between bulletproof and bullet resistant.  What does bulletproof mean to you?  Every bullet bounces?  I.e. Superman skin?  What do you mean by skin?  Does chitin count?  What about fur?